# Callback a function when a label is touched in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

How do I callback a function when label is touched in cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't set a callback function for `CCLabelTTF` or any other Label class, yet there is [CCMenuItemLabel](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d3/dc3/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_menu_item_label.html) you can use.

you first need to create an instance of `CCMenu` class. then you need to allocate `CCMenuItemLabel` instance, using `CCMenuItem::initWithLabel (CCNode *label, CCObject *target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)`. just check how helloworld sample handled it, although it's using CCMenuItemImage, but the base idea is just same in both.